# Derivative of volume of given set

Tags: analysis, measure-theory, partial-differential-equations, geometric-measure-theory

As picture below ,how to compute the $\partial_t |\Omega_t|$ ? The picture below is from the 32 page of *Maximum principles and the method of moving planes*.

~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [Co-area formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coarea_formula) with $g=|\nabla u|^{-1} \chi_{\Omega_t}$ to get

$$ \int_{\Omega_t} dA=\int_t^\infty \left(\int_{\partial \Omega_x} \frac{ds}{|\nabla u|}\right)dx.$$

Differentiating this with respect to $t$ gives the formula you're looking for.